# Аудит postgres при старте и остановке СУБД

Tags: linux, postgresql9.6

необходимо вести аудит СУБД постгреса при остановке и старте сервера. Есть созданная таблица, хочу в нее положить данные, когда сервер был остановлен и запущен. Например, в терминале запускаем СУБД и когда она запустилась написать в таблицу. Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL предоставляет механизм аудита для отслеживания различных событий в базе данных. Можно использовать конфигурационные файлы и функции аудита для определения событий, которые вы хотите отслеживать. Например:
Включение аудита
`audit_trail = on`
Уровень аудита (например, 'all', 'ddl', 'read', 'write', 'misc')
`audit_events = 'all'`.

Для более удобного мониторинга и анализа событий вы можете использовать специальные инструменты, такие как pgBadger или pgAdmin, которые могут агрегировать и визуализировать данные из журналов PostgreSQL.
После остановки и запуска сервера, проанализируйте файлы журнала, чтобы получить информацию о событиях во время этих операций. Файлы журнала могут находиться в указанном вами каталоге (log_directory).